# Какой именно enter нажат?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Как определить, какой из двух enter'ов нажат(num pad или основной)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обработайте сообщение WM_KEYDOWN. В 24 бите lParam будет разница - 0 для обычного Enter, 1 для num pad.

Comment: Ничего себе тонкости. Большое спасибо, займусь.

Comment: а как это поймать в процедуре хуков? Там нет такого, увы

Comment: В любую форму поступают сообщения клавиатуры.

Comment: Обнаружил, благодарю

Answer (score 2):

Прийдется захватить сырую клавиатуру [Raw Input (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536(v=vs.85).aspx)  . В [виртуальной клавиатуре](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), которая пересылает события приложению, нет различий между энтерами.